# How to add CSS styling to Django Input Popup from Incorrect Input

Tags: python, css, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

Looking to add CSS styling (preferably Bootstrap classes) to the error popup on a Django Form CharField when the incorrect length is entered.

I already figured out how to add style to the text input itself (as can be seen in the attrs section of the code), but not sure how to add styling to the popup.

The min length must be 5 and when less than this is entered a popup appears saying "Please lengthen this text to to 5 characters..", that is what I want to style.

```
class CityForm(forms.Form):
    zipcode = forms.CharField(label='zipcode', max_length=5, 
    min_length=5, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter a Zipcode', 'class' : 'form-control form-control-m text-center'}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the min_length = 5 was causing the popup, but it was just a browser popup that wasn't going to be customizable. Ended up removing this part of the code and wrote a custom Django Validator for it.